# async memoized - understanding source code

Tags: javascript, memoization, async.js

From `async.memoize()`, what does the last else block after the comment in this function do?

https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L671

```
async.memoize = function (fn, hasher) {
    var memo = {};
    var queues = {};
    hasher = hasher || function (x) {
        return x;
    };
    var memoized = function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        var callback = args.pop();
        var key = hasher.apply(null, args);
        if (key in memo) {
            callback.apply(null, memo[key]);
        }
        else if (key in queues) {
            queues[key].push(callback);
        }
        else {
            // what does this else block do?
            queues[key] = [callback];
            fn.apply(null, args.concat([function () {
                memo[key] = arguments;
                var q = queues[key];
                delete queues[key];
                for (var i = 0, l = q.length; i < l; i++) {
                  q[i].apply(null, arguments);
                }
            }]));
        }
    };
    memoized.unmemoized = fn;
    return memoized;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `key` is not found in either the `memo` or the `queues` objects (the first two parts of the `if` statement), then it calls the callback and assigns the return value from the callback to `queues[key]` as a one element array.

Then, it calls whatever functions where in the `queue[key]` array.

Comment: thanks, why does it do args.concat( [function() {...} ] ) ? hard to read this one

Comment: I don't claim to understand what the overall function is trying to accomplish (it's pretty obtuse code with no comments), but it has previously popped off the callback from the arguments so it's putting this anonymous function (in an array) back onto the end of the arguments array.  It will end up calling the callback and passing it this arguments array so the callback must be anticipating this type of structure.

Comment: I don't understand if it that else block also memoizes error results.